# Conemu send command to multiple remote sessions

Tags: windows, putty, conemu

I am currently trying to use Conemu with PuTTY to try to easily control some machines. I wanted to send commands to multiple Putty windows at the same time. I tried PuTTYCS but it wouldn't work with the windows already attached to conemu

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old: but here is how:

1. First stack your [putty] sessions in one window using Ctrl + T
2. With your sessions all opened in a window, using the key
   combinations App + G you enable/activate the execution of commands
   on the multiple sessions.

**To disable this**, simply enter same key combinations App + G

**Note:**
The key [App]  (mentioned as VK_APPS in WinUser.h) is located between RightWin and RightControl on the most of keyboard layouts. see - https://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html